# How do you test StoreKit subscription purchases on Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, storekit, watchos

Using a modified version of the following example

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            BackyardList(isSubscribed: isSubscribed, backyardLimit: passStatus.backyardLimit, onOfferSelection: showSubscriptionStore)
            .navigationTitle("Backyard Birds")
            .navigationDestination(for: Backyard.ID.self) { backyardID in
                if let backyard = backyards.first(where: { $0.id == backyardID }) {
                    BackyardTabView(backyard: backyard)
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            ContentUnavailableView("Select a Backyard", systemImage: "bird", description: Text("Pick something from the list."))
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSubscriptionStore) {
            SubscriptionStoreView(groupID: groupID)
        }
        .onInAppPurchaseCompletion { _, purchaseResult in
            guard case .success(let verificationResult) = purchaseResult,
                  case .success(_) = verificationResult else {
                return
            }
            showingSubscriptionStore = false
        }
    }
```

(from Apple's [sample code demonstrating in-app purchases](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/backyard-birds-sample)), I'm unable to complete a sandbox purchase on Apple Watch. I get the error in the UI

> Unable to Purchase App
>
> Sign in with your Apple ID from the Apple Watch app on your iPhone

and printing `purchaseResult` outputs `failure(StoreKit.StoreKitError.unknown)`. An Apple ID is signed into Settings on iOS, as well as the Apple Watch app. This occurs whether or not a separate sandbox Apple ID is signed into Settings under App Store. The subscription options UI appears as expected before attempting to purchase one.